# Streaming to HLS server with ffmpeg and nginx-rtmp-module

Tags: ffmpeg, nginx

I am trying to stream my desktop screen to a HLS server (nginx RTMP module), but I don't know how to go about this. I have tried

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -i :0.0 -f hls http://192.168.1.68/tmp/hls
```

but this returns

```
ffmpeg version N-60313-g6d7119d Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
built on Feb  2 2014 16:01:55 with gcc 4.7 (Debian 4.7.3-4)
configuration: --enable-indev=alsa --enable-gpl --enable-x11grab --enable-libpulse --enable-libopus --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-pthreads
libavutil      52. 63.100 / 52. 63.100
libavcodec     55. 49.101 / 55. 49.101
libavformat    55. 29.100 / 55. 29.100
libavdevice    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
libavfilter     4.  1.102 /  4.  1.102
libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[x11grab @ 0x2823900] device: :0.0 -> display: :0.0 x: 0 y: 0 width: 640 height: 480
[x11grab @ 0x2823900] shared memory extension found
Input #0, x11grab, from ':0.0':
Duration: N/A, start: 1391370026.581568, bitrate: 294617 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[0] / 0x524742), bgr0, 640x480, 294617 kb/s, 29.97 tbr, 1000k tbn, 29.97 tbc
[tcp @ 0x28854c0] Failed to resolve hostname 192.168.10.ts: Name or service not known
Output #0, hls, to 'http://192.168.1.68/tmp/hls':
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavf55.29.100
Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video, yuv420p, 640x480, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo -> mpeg2video)
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Input/output error
```

My `nginx.conf` contains:

```
rtmp {
    server {
            listen 1935;
            chunk_size 4096;

            application live
    {
        live on;
                    record off;

        hls on;
        hls_path /tmp/hls;
        hls_fragment 12s;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the complete `ffmpeg` console output.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Full output added

Comment: `[tcp @ 0x28854c0] Failed to resolve hostname 192.168.10.ts: Name or service not known` looks suspect. Also, does it work if you output to a local file (`output.m3u8`)?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Outputting to a local file appears to be fine

Answer (score 2):

No. In fact, you should stream to nginx-rtmp via RTMP protocol.

`ffmpeg -f x11grab -i :0.0 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 1024k -an -f flv rtmp:/192.168.1.68/live/test`

And you should add something like this to nginx.conf

```
http {
...
server {
    ...
    location /hls {
        types {
            application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
        }
        root /tmp;
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    }
}
...
}
```

Then configure your player to stream source url `http://192.168.1.68/hls/test.m3u8`

Good luck.

Comment: can you paste more of your nginx config?